# Getting output to just what's in the textarea

Tags: html, tinymce, output

how do i get the output to just what's in the textarea instead of tinymce adding a whole html page wrapped aound my content.

Answer (score 1):

plugins : "fullpage", 
theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage"

remove these options from plugin settings

actually the question should have been the other way around

Answer (score 0):

```
tinyMCE.get("elm1").getContent();
```